# how to know which css and js files have been applied to an element

Tags: javascript, css

Suppose I inspect the navbar in a web page in google chrome. How do I know which CSS and js files are being applied to that navbar?

Comment: In the inspector, it should say the file name of the CSS file. The JS file is trickier to identify. For identifying event listeners, I use [this bookmarklet](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2)

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome dev tools you can see what CSS is applied to an element under the "Computed" tab. Scroll down to the attribute such as "font-size" and expand the attribute to see the where the style is set. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

For Javascript view the "Event Listeners" tab to see the Javascript events acting on that element and expand to see where the listener is defined and what it does.

Comment: Note that there are various ways JS could be "applied" to an element that aren't related to event listeners on the element in question.